# In iOS, arcs are malformed for certain start angles

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext, cgpath

I use the following code to draw an arc

```
    double radius = 358.40001058578491;
    startAngle = 0.13541347644783652;
    double center_x= 684;
    double center_y = 440;
    std::complex<double> start1(   std::polar(radius,startAngle) );

    CGPoint targetStart1 = CGPointMake(start1.real() + center_x, start1.imag() +center_y);
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, targetStart1.x, targetStart1.y);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, center_x, center_y, radius, startAngle, 0.785,   0 );
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextSetLineWidth( context,  30 );

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor( context, targetColor.CGColor);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGPathRelease(path);
```

If u check it in retina, it looks like this:

[image]

My arc is the green arc. I have shown the place that the start angle is with a orange line.  As I have shown in the red rectangle, there is an extra thing drawn in the very beginning of the arc. This happens not for all start angles, but only for certain start angles.

Do you have any idea why it happens?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this on device? or simulator?

Comment: @trick14 On both it looks like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original question, you specified a literal starting point that was not quite right and, as a result, Core Graphics will draw a line from that point to the start of the arc. And because that starting point was just a few pixels away from the actual start of the arc, it results in that curious rendering you illustrate in your question.

In your revised question, you're calculating the starting point, but I might suggest calculating it programmatically like so:

```
CGFloat centerX    = 684.0;
CGFloat centerY    = 440.0;
CGFloat radius     = 360.0;
CGFloat startAngle = 0.135;
CGFloat endAngle   = 0.785;

CGFloat startingX = centerX + radius * cosf(startAngle);
CGFloat startingY = centerY + radius * sinf(startAngle);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startingX, startingY);

CGContextAddArc(context, centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, 0);

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 30);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, targetColor.CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

When I calculated it this way, there was no rounding errors that resulted in the artifact illustrated in your original question.

---

Note, if you're not drawing anything before the arc, you can just omit the `CGContextMoveToPoint` call altogether. You only need that "move to point" call if you've drawn something before the arc and don't want the path connecting from that `CGContextGetPathCurrentPoint` to the start of the arc.

Comment: your starting point is off because you started at an angle of 0.0135, when the starting angle in the question is 0.135

Comment: Good catch. But when I use .135, I get starting point of 1040.72, 488.45, which is still different than OP's.

Comment: @Rob Please see the update for the way I computed the starting point.

Comment: @Pegah -- my calculations agree with Rob's, but I'm seeing the problem in the 7.1 simulator regardless of which starting point I use.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the values. Now the start point X = 1039.1 and start point Y = 488.3. The radius that I was actually using was a bit different with what I originally had written here.

Comment: @Pegah Alright, I finally understand the issue. In order for this to work correctly, you must compute the exact same starting point that Core Graphics uses as the starting point for the arc. Otherwise, Core Graphics tries to draw a line from your starting point to the arc starting point, and since that line is 30 pixels wide, it's quite noticeable, even if it's only 0.01 pixels long. So you have to use Rob's exact code for the calculations.  Also, all variables should be declared as CGFloat, not double, since Core Graphics uses CGFloat for everything.

Comment: @Rob Could you please update ur answer with Comments from @user2286109?

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks a lot. I was since several days trying to find why it does not work.

Comment: @user3386109 So as a rule, when I am using Core Graphics, I should use CGFloat, correct?

Comment: @Pegah Yes, Core Graphics uses CGFloats for just about everything.  I've found a better way to calculate the starting point, so I'll edit Rob's answer to add that in a few minutes.

Comment: @Rob I have added to the answer with the best of intentions.  Feel free to roll back if I have improperly intruded.